# SAPUI5 Destination alternative without Cloud Platform

Tags: sapui5

I have a gateway service which I want to use in an SAPUI5 application which is not hosted on the SAP Cloud Platform. I was wondering what the alternatives of destinations are.

I've tried creating a oData model with the service URL, but it is returning an error.

[image]

```
createODataModel: function () {
        var serviceUrl = "http://<server>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/sap/<GW_SERVICE>/";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(serviceUrl);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "test");
    },
```

It doesn't accept the HTTP prefix. Is there any way around this?

Comment: See _SAP Web Dispatcher_. It can act as a reverse proxy and forward requests to different systems.

Comment: Where do You want tp launch Your SAPUI5 app?
If You have SAP Gateway on-premis and want to develop apps in the WebIDE You have to configure destinations in Cloud Platform.

If You deploy Your apps to Gateway, You don't have to do additional proxy settings.

Comment: destinations are reverse proxies. you can put whatever you like in it. the mixed content problem most likely stems from the mixing of http and https.